# Break up of daily stats in User Summary

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been searching for an hour now and I am not able to find a similar question. So pardon me if this has been asked before.

Can we have this feature in user's summary?

[image]

**EDIT**: I know upvoting and downvoting works differently in meta. So if you are downvoting then I am assuming that you don't want or like this feature. In such a case if you don't mind, can you please leave a comment as to why you don't think this feature is useful **OR** perhaps leave an answer if it has **not been** answered/commented below? Hope I am not asking for too much?

Comment: What about reputation changes due to edits, user removed, association bonus, downvote to other's answer,.....

Comment: @Azik: Very good point :) The above is just a basic demonstration. As a community if we want this feature then we can think of these as well

Comment: if a user got 5 rep on one upvote, it is very noisy to show all the other things with zero.

Comment: @Azik: That is just one scenario. The stats is not for the world to see but for the individual to analyze :)